# Something like MATLAB Cody for Mathematica? (Learning through exercises.)

Tags: education, game, example

At some rainy days, when I realise again the TV program is getting worse and worse ... I visit [Cody](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody):

> Cody™ is a MATLAB Central game that challenges and expands your
>   knowledge of MATLAB. As a web service provided to the community, Cody
>   helps you sharpen your programming skills by solving problems and
>   interacting with other members of the community.

It's unlike Mathematica.SE:  The equivalent of Mathematica.SE would be ['Answers'](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers), a platform for questions and answers.

In Cody, community members program little games/challenges for others. You can try to solve these challenges by typing code directly into the browser. Sending your solution will be checked and rated instantly.

I definitely had some fun with *Cody*, so I'm wondering if there is something similar for *Mathematica*?

Or how do you improve your *Mathematica* skills in a playful way?

Comment: Sounds like *mathematica.stackexchange.com* without the blood in the water ;-)

Comment: It's unlike mathematica.se: In cody community members program little games/challenges for others. You can try to solve this challenges by typing code directly into the browser. Sending your solution will be checked and rated instantly.

Comment: @Kuba If you don't know what cody is, you might give it a try to see how it works. ;-)

Comment: @Kuba It's more like [codegolf.stackexchange.com](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) but only for `Mathematica`/`MatLab`(in this case) code.

Comment: @rasher Duuun dun duuun dun dun dun dun dun dun dun ...

Comment: @Phab Actually, it's like [ProjectEuler](https://projecteuler.net/), but only Mathematica allowed and checked.

Comment: @Kuba As far as I can tell, this is a collection of programming exercises, ranging from trivial to advanced, with automated solution checking.  This sort of thing can indeed be very useful when learning any subject (that's why we do it a lot for maths classes).  It's not like Mathematica.SE as people solve the exercises with the aim of learning, and many of the exercises are geared towards beginners (and would instantly get closed here).

Comment: @Kuba [Wolfram Programming Lab](https://vimeo.com/118741155) might be something similar, I'm not actually sure what it is.  I found it by digging around on the paclet server, try `PacletFindRemote["WPL*"]`.  You can download the paclets, but most of them are unfinished.   It looks like a so far unreleased product.